# Receiving call / Proximity Sensor

Tags: android

I am developing an App where I can receive call when mobile is brought near to ear, I have done that, now problem is call is received even when something come close to sensor inside my pocket. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Even I was struggled and found no solution. We can't determine whether mobile is inside pocket or in hand or else on table using proximity Sensor!. The term `proximity` itself says that it was a Sensor which will be fired when an Object comes closer to mobile...

Comment: @GopalRao so is there any other way where i can do this work.

Comment: hmmmmmm.... AFAIK, there is no solution... but blindly don't depend on my comment! Once try yourself. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you have to check at what angle the device is rotated in x,y,z direction before taking a call,(generally in a 'L' shape from pocket to ear) like the angle movements made when the device is lifted up to the ear.Then you will be able to distinguish between a call and device in pocket.